# I am trying to make buttons dissapear when something is selected in a UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uipickerview

I am trying to make buttons dissapear when something is selected in a UIPickerView. I already declared the buttons in the .h and the .m files. All buttons are linked correctly. I will paste the code down below. Please help me.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:  (NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView.tag == 1) {

        calculateButtonPressed2.hidden = YES;
        calculateButtonPressed3.hidden = YES;
        calculateButtonPressed4.hidden = YES;
        calculateButtonPressed5.hidden = YES;
        calculateButtonPressed6.hidden = YES;

} else {



}
```

Comment: did you assign tag to pickerview?

Comment: I think you should replace `pickerView.tag == 1` with `row == 1`

Comment: What's the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: @rmaddy  I got an error saying that said Use of undeclared identifier 'calculateButtonPressed2'. I got this error for every single button.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried to run the code and found It's working.
If you wanted to disappear completely then you can put the code given below. The button will be disappear

```
 -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{



        if(row>-1) // not required to put but for a safe side we can put it.
       {   
        calculateButtonPressed2.hidden = YES;
        calculateButtonPressed3.hidden = YES;
        calculateButtonPressed4.hidden = YES;
        calculateButtonPressed5.hidden = YES;
        calculateButtonPressed6.hidden = YES;
    }
```

// Also If you wanted to hide on some particular row in that case

```
      if(row== RowNumber){   
            calculateButtonPressed2.hidden = YES;
            calculateButtonPressed3.hidden = YES;
            calculateButtonPressed4.hidden = YES;
            calculateButtonPressed5.hidden = YES;
            calculateButtonPressed6.hidden = YES;
        }
```

Please let me know if It's working.

Comment: I did what you said but I got an error saying that said Use of undeclared identifier 'calculateButtonPressed2'. I got this error for every single button.

Comment: use self if you not synthesize your buttons.




            self.calculateButtonPressed2.hidden = YES;
            self.calculateButtonPressed3.hidden = YES;
            self.calculateButtonPressed4.hidden = YES;
            self.calculateButtonPressed5.hidden = YES;
            self.calculateButtonPressed6.hidden = YES;